# How to display Grayscale image after changing the indexing in C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmapimage

I have a Grayscale image which I am pulling from the DB (it is in Bytes). I want to draw some boxes using graphics object on it and then display this image. This is what was coded before -

```
public byte[] DrawOverlayOnGreyscaleImage(byte[] buffer, List<ImagingTransaction.ImagingTransactionField> TransactionFieldList, BLLImageType imageType)
{
    //Load image into a bitmap object via first going into a MemoryStream 
    MemoryStream msBitmap = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    Bitmap BitmapObj = null;
    BitmapObj = new Bitmap(msBitmap);
    int bmwidth = BitmapObj.Width;
    int bmheight = BitmapObj.Height;

    // draw some text on top
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(BitmapObj);
```

Because of the changes in the way the image is now generated (Format8bppIndexed) the Graphics object threw an exception - "A graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format". So I changed the Bitmap to be Format24bppRGB. Now, there is no exception. But after I draw boxes on the image and try to save it, the image is all  black. This is because in case of "Grayscale" images R=G=B. This is lost after making it non indexed. I change the Bitmap to be again Indexed (Format8bbIndexed). Change the ColorPalette, but nothing helps. I still get the image to be totally black. Please help. My new code is as follows -

```
public byte[] DrawOverlayOnGreyscaleImage(byte[] buffer, List<ImagingTransaction.ImagingTransactionField> TransactionFieldList, BLLImageType imageType)
{

    //Load image into a bitmap object via first going into a MemoryStream 
    MemoryStream msBitmap = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    Bitmap BitmapObj = null;
    BitmapObj = new Bitmap(msBitmap);
    int bmwidth = BitmapObj.Width;
    int bmheight = BitmapObj.Height;

    Bitmap tmp = new Bitmap(BitmapObj.Width, BitmapObj.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tmp);

    Rectangle srcRect;
    int RectWidth;
    int RectHeight;
    Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 3);

    foreach (ImagingTransaction.ImagingTransactionField Field in TransactionFieldList)
    {

        // first, do they want to see the rectangles
        if (imageType == BLLImageType.GreyScale_With_FieldRectangles || imageType == BLLImageType.GreyScale_With_FieldRectangles_And_Field_Data)
        {
            RectWidth = Field.LowerRightX - Field.UpperLeftX;
            RectHeight = Field.LowerRightY - Field.UpperLeftY;

            // sanity check for negative values
            if (RectWidth <= 0)
                RectWidth = 10;
            if (RectHeight <= 0)
                RectHeight = 10;

            srcRect = new Rectangle(Field.UpperLeftX, Field.UpperLeftY, RectWidth, RectHeight);
            g.DrawRectangle(myPen, srcRect);
        }
        // now, do they want to see the text to the lower right of the field
        if (imageType == BLLImageType.GreyScale_With_Field_Data || imageType == BLLImageType.GreyScale_With_FieldRectangles_And_Field_Data)
        {
            g.DrawString(Field.FieldValue, new Font("Tahoma", 12), Brushes.Red, new PointF(Field.LowerRightX, Field.LowerRightY)); ;
        }

    }

    MemoryStream msBitmapWithRectangle = new MemoryStream();

    // Save to memory using the Jpeg format
    Bitmap tmp2 = new Bitmap(tmp.Width, tmp.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    ColorPalette pal = tmp2.Palette;
    for (int i = 0; i < pal.Entries.Length; i++)
    {
        // create greyscale color table
        pal.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
    }
    tmp2.Palette = pal;
    tmp2.Save(msBitmapWithRectangle, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    // read to end
    byte[] ByteArrayWithRectangle = msBitmapWithRectangle.GetBuffer();


    // cleanup
    tmp.Dispose();
    tmp2.Dispose();
    BitmapObj.Dispose();
    msBitmap.Close();
    msBitmapWithRectangle.Close();
    return ByteArrayWithRectangle;
}
```

Comment: Sorry may be I'm missing something, but it seems that tmp2 is created but never filled with original bitmap. In practise you save in memory perfectly black rectangle.

Comment: Thanks a million. Dont know how I missed taht.

Comment: I will add so like an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that tmp2 is created but never filled with original bitmap, so you create a perfectly black rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new bitmap in the BPP and size you need, and draw the image, and then draw the rectange.